# Inserting data into Hive with lesser columns than Target table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have table (with matching columns) with 18 columns. I need to add it into target table, which have 319 columns. Simple Insert Into doesn't work, mismatch columns error appears. Maybe there is another solution or turn around for doing that ?

Comment: You can try the following :
`INSERT INTO target_table (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM source_table;`